# Trouble with embedded document instantiation

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Using Mongooose / Node.JS. I am trying to create a user object when a user registers. What I would like to do is to be able to access the CandidateProfile portion and populate it later when the user enters that data. Can someone suggest what's the next step I need to take. I have tried quite a few option but I can't seem to be able to create the CandidateProfile document linked to the User document.

```
var CandidateProfileSchema = new Schema({
  //Info
  name: String,
  email: {type: String, lowercase: true},
  mobile: Number,
  isITProfessional: Boolean,
  isMobileVerified: Boolean,
  isEmailVerified: Boolean,
  isRegistrationCompleted: Boolean,
  active: Boolean,
  // MORE FIELDS
});  

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String,
  candidateProfile: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CandidateProfileSchema'}
});
```

Comment: First of all, it's not an embedded document but a referenced one (there is a huge difference), secondly you will create your profile later and just attach it to the user, see the examples in mongoose docs

Comment: see here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: populate helped. Thanks yarons & Vsevolod!